# runtime error in code for solving smallest even divisible

Tags: c++

The problem was to find the smallest even number that is divisible by 17 and 32 and has a square root greater than 120.

This code outputs 32 which obviously isn't true. Can anyone spot my error?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int i = 1;
    if(i%2!=0){
        i++;
    }
    while(i%17!=0 && i%32!=0 && sqrt(i)<120){
        i+=2;
    }
    cout<<i<<endl;
}
```

Comment: The reason for setting i = 1 is because the prompt said i must start at 1.

Answer (score 2):

`i%17!=0 && i%32!=0 && sqrt(i)<120` here is the problem. Your stopping condition should be:

while (it is **NOT** (Divisible by 17 **AND** Divisible by 18 **AND** its root more than 120)).

This is equal to:

```
while(!(i%17==0 && i%32==0 && sqrt(i)>120))
```

Or even shorter using [Demorgan Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan's_laws):

```
while(i%17!=0 || i%32!=0 || sqrt(i)<=120)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your boolean expression is wrong. You need to loop while any of the conditions is true since it has to end when i % 17 == 0, i % 32 == 0 or sqrt(i) <= 120. The negation of this is an or'd expression.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is

```
#include <math.h>       /* ceil */
#include <iostream>
int main ()
{
    std::cout<<ceil((120*120)/(32*17))*(32*17);
}
```

Do not use loops for simple math problems

Answer (score 0):

To improve efficiency, you should start with LCM of 17 & 32 i.e. 544 and then work your way up instead of starting from 1.